# Can a rails app (on local machine) connect to a remote database (on staging server) without having mysql setup on the local machine?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to get rid of mysql on local machine - because it is using a lot of resources - and connect to staging server's db when I need to work on front-end, etc? Can you describe how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe how to do it? or share a post about it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can connect by specifying the required credentials (username,password) along with host ip

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: xxxxxxxxxx
  host: 192.168.x.xxx
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: this requires a mysql2 adapter, right? I don't have a local mysql setup.

Comment: You don't need mysql setup, just the adaptor

Comment: if you are not using mysql2 adapter then use mysql adapter itself
replace mysql2 adapter with mysql